# How to sync Gerrit with Git and rewrite history?

Tags: git, gerrit

We have a messy situation here. We have a Git-Gerrit system and we have found a series of GIT commits by one of the users to be unacceptable. What's more, this user issued git reset soft after each commit, leaving his HEAD pointing to the same commit all the time. (He was actually making fake changes and pushing them to the central repository, just to test the triggering of a build. He should have used git commit amend actually, he wouldn't have littered Gerrit with useless changes.) So we want to get rid of all these fake commits, possibly with a git hard reset. But what would happen to Gerrit? If we want to go back to the last good commit, should we abandon the Gerrit changes corresponding to each of those commits? Then do a git hard reset? Or does abandoning a Gerrit change automatically delete the respective Git commit in the central repository? And when we finally sort this out, how should the user sync in with the new, cleaned-up repos? Rewriting history is not such a terrible thing here as only this one developer is working on the code from now. So how should we proceed?

Comment: Okay, I can simplify this question as it seems too intimidating. :-) What does Gerrit's abandon change cause? Does it reject the respecting Git commit? Now we would be okay to leave Git history as it is, we only want the user's repo to be synchronized with the central one, we could tolerate all those fake commits, but it would be nice to keep Gerrit clean at least. Perhaps Gerrit abandon is the cure for all, it would simply undo the Git commits as well?

Comment: Did the user just push the changes for review (i.e. the changes are still open) or did he afterwards push them the branch (i.e. the changes are submitted and available to everyone)?

Comment: @Magnus Bäck : The user just pushed the changes for review. So it's the user's local tree that has to be synced somehow with the Gerrit branch after abandons. The central repo is intact.

Comment: Okay. Then s/he can just start a new local branch based on origin/master (or whatever the upstream branch is called) and toss his/her old branch.

Comment: @Magnus Bäck : Okay, we'll do something like that. We decided not to be too strict about eradicating these fake changes without any trace whatsoever as it is risky and we can just continue from the last good commit. So abandoning  and syncing the head is enough.